# Changing iOS app name in iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

We are planning to change the name of our current live app in the next version. App's bundle id and app's unique Apple id in iTunes will not going to be changed, so it will be the same app with only the name changed.

My question is that, how this works with redirecting user to the iTunes for app rating.

Currently we are redirecting user with the following URL.

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-name-string/xxxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8
```

How i can redirect my app in the new version when the name in iTunes will be changed. Do i have to just replace `app-name-string` with `new-app-name-string` and the url will become like `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/new-app-name-string/xxxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8`

Will it work that easily? Also how about the users which have my old app version. So, when i will update the app name in the new version in iTunes connect, the app store rating url will be changed and the old url which is embedded with the old app name will no longer remain valid in the old app.

How i can handle all this scenario so that nothing will break.

Comment: There is a simple way to find out. Once the new version of your app is on the AppStore, you can just *share* the link from inside the AppStore / iTunes, which will show you what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work better: 
`https://itunes.apple.com/app/id{yourAppId}`

Answer (score 0):

Depends how your particular app is developed but app rating always works against app id - not name.  You shouldn't be hardcoding URLs in your app to the app store.